# Slim Framework - PHP not routing correctly - any ideas?

Tags: php, xampp, slim

I am running a Web Server using XAMPP - it runs on 'http://localhost/mvc-framework/public/' as the root.

But when I try and navigate using the 'Contact' link it goes to 'http://localhost/contact' and I get a '404' error.

My `routes.php` currently looks like this:

```
<?php
// Routes

$app->get('mvc-framework/public/contact', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // Render index view
    return $this->view->render($response, 'contact-form.phtml', $args);
});

$app->get('/[{name}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // Sample log message
    $this->logger->info("Slim-Skeleton '/' route");

    // Render index view
    return $this->view->render($response, 'about.phtml', $args);
});
```

Is there somewhere obvious I am going wrong?

Comment: Saying `it runs on 'http://localhost/mvc-framework/public/' as the root.` is a little bit confusing. Could you please clarify that? Also, could you please let us know your project's directory structure, the value of `DocumentRoot` from web server configurations and also contents of `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

The `public/` directory is only the DocumentRoot of the webserver and therefore should never be part of the url base path.

The correct url: `http://localhost/mvc-framework/`

When you run your Slim app within a sub-directory of the DocumentRoot, you also have to define the Slim basePath. In your specific case it's `/mvc-framework`:

```php
$app->setBasePath('/mvc-framework');
```

The routes should be defined without the base path:

```php
<?php

$app->get('/contact', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // Render index view
    return $this->view->render($response, 'contact-form.phtml', $args);
});
```

Also make sure to add the correct `.htaccess` files when you run a Slim app within a sub-directory of the DocumentRoot. [Slim 4 BasePath](https://github.com/selective-php/basepath#installation)

Comment: Hi @odan - thanks for your help - it looks like I wasn't running the Apache server from the correct location - I changed the 'DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"' in 'httpd.conf' and restarting the server - now it works perfectly! Thanks for the help with the routes.php!